# Why does Firestore in React with Typescript give error of undefined value in uncaught promise showing up when querying data?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

All I'm attempting to do is to grab the names of the docs which have an array inside of them called users with a specifc uid.

Here is how my Firestore is setup:
[image]

Rooms is the root, and the docs that would show up in this case would be "RP Rooms Community" and "Test Room"

I run this code

```js
const GetRooms = async () => {
        const roomsRef = collection(db, 'Rooms');
        const userRoomsQuery = query(
            roomsRef,
            where('users', 'array-contains', currentUser.uid)
        );
    console.log(userRoomsQuery);
    };
```

It gives me this error:

[image]

Any idea on what I  can change to get this error to not keep showing up ? Somehow the doc info does get through sometimes if I'm not refreshing and instead change something in the webapp that causes the doc data to load correctly with the console.log

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(currentUser.uid)`? It's mostly likely undefined

Comment: Yes my currentUser.uid is ok, I already tried that one.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your where() doesn't meet the prescribed method, e.g

```
let collectionRef = firestore.collection('col');

collectionRef.where('foo', '==', 'bar').get().then(querySnapshot => {
  querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
    console.log(`Found document at ${documentSnapshot.ref.path}`);
  });
});
```

Check here for more details
https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#where

Comment: So this seems like it would worked I checked the docs you described and I might have to switch over to this.

The only issue is that I'm using the docs from here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

I'm using the module firebase/firestore in the imports where "Firestore" on it's own doesn't exist. I added just "firebase" which has all the things I supposedly need.